# Icons in App store display blurred

Tags: mac-appstore, macos, icon

I did a clean install on macOS Sierra 10.12 on my MacBook Air 13.3" early 2015 and found out that most of the icons in App Store are blurred.

Searched the web for a bit, finding references saying that this issue may be caused by the app developers who forgot to update the icon to better image quality. Some references also suggest deleting applications and downloading them again in order for the icons to be updated. Also [no custom fonts](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2132399?tstart=0) were installed on this machine.

These references do not really apply to my case, because blurred icons are in the App Store itself and app developer is Apple. Have a look on the attached images:

[image: Xcode blurred icon]

[image]

I am guessing that my MacBook Air supports only up to 1440x900 resolution with [128 dpi](http://dpi.lv/) and icons were designed to support higher dpi screens. That sounds a bit ridiculous.

What are you thoughts guys? What could be causing this problem?

Comment: What you're seeing is not blurriness but rather transparency artifacts. That is rather bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same Problem .. the fix (for me) was go to systempreferences  - Accsessibility - Zoom - Smooth Images. Turn smooth images OFF and all icons back to "normal".  Good Luck